# Memory Mapped Files - Map a structure not a file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shared-memory

I'm very new to Memory Mapped Files, and I'm a little lost on something.

I know that if I had a file, I could load it and access it from various processes at once using MMaps.

But in my situation, I'm creating a DLL attached to Process A, and that DLL has been given a pointer to a cSurface which Process A has prepared. I need to share that cSurface's data with Process B. I really don't want to have to call up a blank MMap and copy my Process A's surface into it, only to copy it out again in process B.

Is it possible to map my surface as if it were a file so the MMap already points to the surface data when it's created (as it would were I loading SomeTextFile.txt)?

My plan, in theory, would be to receive a pointer to the surface in Proc A, tell windows to share that surface's memory with a given name, and use Mutexes to coordinate access - the idea being that both processes read the same physical copy of the surface with no cumbersome copying.

Is that possible?

Comment: Just thought I'd make my post a little clearer. Suppose I have a huge buffer called `char buffer[SUPER_MASSIVE]` and a huge file called `hSuperMassiveFile`. I could share SuperMassiveFile by doing `CreateFileMapping( hSuperMassiveFile, ... )`, but I'd like to do the same with my buffer. Is there some way to do `CreateFileMapping( (HANDLE) buffer, ...)` instead and share my buffer without having to request an empty map and then `CopyMemory()` my buffer into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments.

I did some further research and found the answer.

You can use Memory Mapped Files to share either a *file*, or a *blank memory space*. If you want to share data already initialised in memory prior to setting up the map, you have to create a blank map and subsequently copy your data into it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's all there in the documentation of CreateFileMapping.

You can give your memory mapped file a name. If another process open a mmap with the same name it will point to the same memory. It the handle in CreateFileMapping is put to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE it keeps it purely in memory. Check the documentation of [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That much I know, my issue is making the MMap start out containing my data. If my data were in a _file_, and I did `CreateFileMapping( hMyFile, ... );` then the map would automatically contain the contents of MyFile.    But my data is in memory, and it's huge. If I do `CreateFileMapping( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ...);` then I get back a pointer to an uninitialised wasteland, which I then have to copy my massive buffer into, taking time. I'd prefer it if there was a way to make the Map start off pointing to my buffer from the moment it's made.

Comment: I'm creating a DLL, and the buffer is made by the parent application. The parent gives me the pointer to the buffer and its size as parameters in a function. So from what I can see, my options are either to copy the buffer into a MMapped region, or somehow map the region that the buffer's already in.